# Javascript: Change Url without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, url

I am in a page with url

```
https://mysite.com/tst/v1/my-app/var/$%5Btest_new_var%5D.
```

On click i want to change the url to

```
https://mysite.com/tst/v1/my-app/" without reloading the page.
```

How can i do that?

please help,
Thanks.

Comment: @DanielNill there are perfectly valid reasons to do this if you want to create linkable ajax applications.

Answer (score 3):

In newer browsers that support `history.pushState` you can replace the url without reloading.

Lets say a user browses to `http://example.com/ernie.html`

```
window.history.pushState({ foo: "bar" }, "page 2", "bert.html");
```

Will change the address bar to `http://example.com/bert.html`, but won't cause the browser to load bert.html or even check that bert.html exists.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: This is useful when you are using ajax to load the page or do some searching ,you can retain the previous state by checking the get params